# Can't open AWS EC2 instance using Putty

Tags: amazon-ec2, putty

I did the `ec2 instance` setup and converted private key pair to `.ppk` format.
When I try to open the instance it's displaying the following error in Putty:

`unable to open connection to [host_name] host not found`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Please place some code

Comment: Does the ec2 have public IP and you are using same to connect? Is your security groups allowing port 22 from your source pc/internet?

Answer (score 0):

This is a DNS question. Open a command window and type "nslookup [your hostname]" where [your hostname] is the name of the server you are trying to connect to. If it does not find an IP then you (or someone) needs to add your new server to DNS.
As asked above, does your instance even have a public IP address? If not then you will need to set up VPN for your VPC.